# Community ad has "infinite" clicks

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising

If you visit [the stats for our brand new ad](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/567), you will see the following:

[image: Ad stats screenshot]

That's right, we have ∞ clicks per day.

Okay, so maybe I'm nitpicking. And it's probably got something to do with a 0 in a denominator. But it's still a bug...

Comment: And I thought only hashem is  ∞

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good catch! We'll make sure that can't happen in the future.